# Querying Django model when max_allowed_packet in MySQL is exceeded

Tags: mysql, django, django-1.6, operationalerror

So I've got this periodic task of sending an automated report to the user every month. The problem I encountered while generating the report data was that the `MySQL DB` has tons of report data for each user, so when I try to query on the User model, I get `OperationalError: (1153, "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes")`.

I've gone into the `dbshell` and check what the setting for that variable is, and it's the max allowed value (1 GB).

So I'm basically stuck here. Is there any way to get all the data without hitting that `OperationalError`?

The code is as follows (I've put in dummy names as I can't reveal company information) -

```
user_ids = list(Model1.objects.filter(param=param_value).values_list('user_id', flat=True)) # returns 143992 user_ids
users = User.objects.filter(user_id__in=user_ids)
```

I then try to iterate over `users`, but I hit the `OperationalError`.

I've also tried to split up the queryset like so -

```
slices = []
step = 1000
while True:
    sliced_queryset = users[step-1000:step]
    slices.append(sliced_queryset)
    step += 1000
    if sliced_queryset.count() < 1000:
        break
```

But I hit the same error for `.count()`.

Comment: It's hard to help because you included any code or the full traceback in your question. Perhaps you can split your query into multiple queries so that you don't fetch as much data.

Comment: I've also tried splitting the query, but I get the same error. Also, there is no traceback. I just get `OperationalError` on trying to iterate the `users` queryset.

Comment: Instead of slicing users, slice `user_ids` instead, e.g. `users1 = User.objects.filter(user_id__in=user_ids[:1000])`. Remember that `.count()` does a separate query, so it's more efficient to use `len(sliced_queryset)` if you are fetching the queryset anyway.

Comment: @Alasdair - thanks, slicing `user_ids` instead of `users` seems to work. But what if in the future, I get the same problem for `user_ids` too?

Comment: I can't really help with that because it's a hypothetical question about dummy code. You would have to adjust the query (e.g use a smaller slice or perhaps write raw SQL).

Comment: @Alasdair - thanks